# windows authentication error (only with a lot of data)

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-authentication, http-status-code-401

I have an ASP.net website running under IIS6. In one .aspx page the user has to enter data which is then stored into a database. The amount of data can vary. The project uses Windows Authentication.

So far everything worked, but once the data exceeds a certain amount, the website asks again for the credentials. When I click cancel a 401 error is returned, when I enter username/password a 12152 error (after some time of processing). I have tried it with IE6 and IE9 (also in IE8 mode).
Any ideas what could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than one month I was finally able to solve it: I had to increase the MaxHttpCollectionKeys-settings in the web.config file.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
</appSettings>
```

After this modification the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an execution timeout, the default is 110 seconds.  Try changing the executionTimeout and maxRequestLength attributes of the httpRuntime configuration.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="104856" />
```

Comment: I don’t think it’s an execution timeout.
50 rows finish under 1 second; 51 rows take more than 110 seconds!
I changed executionTimeout and maxRequestLength, still same weird behavior. I am always asked for username/password when the data exceeds a certain amount.